# Given two points calculate a third point in a way that three point construct an equilateral triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles

So I have two points lets say `A(x1,y1)` and `B(x2,y2)`. I want to find a point `C` (there will be two points) in which if you connect the points you will have an equilateral triangle. I know that if I draw a circle from each point with radius of equal to `AB` I will find the point `C` at the intersection of these two circles. But I don't know how to calculate that point.

Comment: there will be two points of intersection of the two circles so two possible locations for point $C$

Comment: @Vasya Yes I know that, I already stated that in my answer. I want to calculate these two points.

Comment: Do you know complex numbers?

Comment: Instead of drawing circles and find the intersection, why not to rotate $B$ with respect to $A$ for $60^\circ$ to get $C(x_3,y_3)$. In matrix notations, this becomes

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_3\\ y_3\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ y_1\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}\frac12 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac12\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_2-x_1\\ y_2-y_1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @achillehui perfect. Can you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment turned to answer per request.

Instead of drawing circles and find the intersection, one can rotate $B$ with respect to $A$ for $\pm 60^\circ$ to get $C(x_3,y_3)$. In matrix notation, the formula is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_3\\ y_3\end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ y_1\end{bmatrix} +  
\begin{bmatrix}\frac12 & \mp \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ 
\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac12\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}x_2-x_1\\ y_2-y_1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $C(x_o, y_o)$
$$AB=\sqrt{((x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$$
The following must happen:
$$AC=BC=AB$$
Or else:
$$AC=AB \ and \ BC=AB$$
And you solve the two equations.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r=AB=\sqrt{((x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$. The equation of the circle radius of $AB$ and $A$ as the center will be $(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=r^2$. The equation of the circle radius of $AB$ and $B$ as the center will be $(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2=r^2$.

Thus you need to solve $(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2$. Simplifying this we'll get $-2x_1x+x_1^2-2y_1y+y_1^2=-2x_2x+x_1^2-2y_2y+y_2^2$. 
Now substitute $y=y_1+\sqrt{r^2-(x-x_1)^2}$ and solve the resulting equation to find $x$